# After Upgrade PHP to 8.1 version - flock(): supplied resource is not a valid stream resource

Tags: magento2, php, upgrade, reindex

I have Magento v2.4.5-p1 and after php version upgrade to 8.1 when running the command: **index:reindex** i get this error for each index: **flock(): supplied resource is not a valid stream resource**.

Has anyone experienced this? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Like this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247507/fclose-18-is-not-a-valid-stream-resource) I have a third party extension that was causing me to get the error. Adding validation helped solve the problem.

As it was:

```
        @flock($pointer, LOCK_UN);
        @fclose($pointer);
```

My fix:

```
    if (is_resource($pointer) && get_resource_type($pointer) == 'stream') {
        @flock($pointer, LOCK_UN);
        @fclose($pointer);
    }
```